# Sourcetree Installation - Atlassian Login Stuck

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to install the SourceTree application on my system. At the step as shown in the image below, I tried logging in through an existing account or otherwise going to the My Atlassian account as well, but I couldn't proceed any further. Can someone please help me out over this? I am able to login but what next?
[image: Issue]

Comment: Tried it multiple times , with both the options but no progress ! Going to the atlassian and logging in gives a free license to download but no option to import it further.

Comment: same issue here. I reinstalled the previous version to keep my work going

Comment: I've tried uninstalling, restarting, clearing cache, reverting to IE as default browser, nothing seems to get it past this step in the wizard.

Comment: I used the 'Use an existing..' button, log out, log back in and it went through.

Comment: Same problem on Win 7 with versions 3.3.4, 3.3.6. Solved by downgrading to 3.1.2

Answer (score 49):

Tested and working workaround. (Windows 7 x64)

1. Run the installer for the latest version of SourceTree (For the moment 2.3.1.0), close it when you get the blank login window.
2. [Download](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d6fb44b93e5a12bfd7c94cf92da2f195) the `accounts.json` file and change `YOUR EMAIL HERE` to your email.
3. Create an empty `passwd.txt` file.
4. Add these files into `%LocalAppData%\Atlassian\SourceTree`
5. Rerun the installer. It should detect the account and password from those files and bypass the request for a login.

To see the evolution/resolution of this problem see this [thread](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-4741)

Most Recent Version Tested : "SourceTreeSetup-3.4.10"

Comment: The seem to have fix this problem in the new Version (2.3.5.0) ? Did someone still have this problem ?

Comment: Just tested for Windows on 2.3.5.0 and i still cannot go past the login screen. In this version the loading spinner is stuck in an endless loop. Would love to see a fix..

Comment: This worked against installer: `SourceTreeSetup-2.4.7.0.exe`. (I also massively turned down all the IE security settings  first, given all the atlassian forums talking about that)

Comment: @ChrisMarisic have you try with the original path first ? : C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree

Comment: @MrRubix `%LocalAppData%` is resolved to the system drive and the current user, you can copy & paste the path in the answer now directly into file explorer (or save dialog). It no longer requires any hand editing.

Comment: Newer `accounts.json` file also has `EmailHash` field which is bcrypt hash of `Email`. It can be generated using any bycrypt generator e.g. https://bcrypt-generator.com – Abdul Rauf 40 mins ago

Answer (score 5):

If you stuck with this screen

[image]

**Follow these steps**

**1**. From a working installed system collect the accounts.json and password files

[image]

**2**. copy and paste the account.json and password files(the above copied files) into the C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree folder in your system.

**3**. Rerun the installer(It should detect the account and password from those files and bypass the request for a login)

Comment: There are 2 folders 'SourceTree' and 'SourceTree.exe_Url_iiq3na5yd1e1at4rm0gqt1pves3cma1i'. In my case, I copied the second one entierly and some files from the first one. And it worked out!

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was to

1. Click on the "Use an existing account" Button
2. Log out
3. Log back in with my credentials

Presto is worked!

Answer (score 4):

Most likely we're using a different version of the installer, but I had exactly the same problem with version 2.1.2.5. Tried everything I could find on the web to no avail.

What worked for me in the end was to disable **pop-up blocking in IE**. You can either do it globally or adding "*.atlassian.com" to your allowed sites:

[image: IE Privacy Settings]

Not a very intuitive solution but it worked.

I believe there are multiple causes to this problem and I understand this solution might not work for all. It seems to me though that it always boils down to the installer not being able to go past the URL below:
https://id.atlassian.com/login?application=sourcetree&continue=https://id.atlassian.com/profile/profile.action

In my case it was pop-up blocker's fault, in other cases it seems changing the [internet security settings to Medium or Low](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/quot-Use-an-existing-account-quot-login-hangs-with-white-screen/qaq-p/410835) does the trick.

Comment: This was what finally did it for me, with Sourcetree v2.3.5. Login window generates a popup requesting permission to follow a link from auth.atlassian.com to id.atlassian.com (Trusted Site). Nothing worked until I could see & answer that pop-up.

Comment: Works for me, using v2.5.5, two years after the answer is written.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem today.I cleared cache of my browser and tried to login again and it worked for me.
Have you tried clearing your browsers cache?

Answer (score 1):

Yet another answer for this question. I was trying to install to Windows Server 2016 running as a VM. In the end I found the simplest solution was to use Server Manager to disable the IE Enhanced Security Configuration. That allowed me to see the login screen, actually login, etc. I also note that the above solution by Mr Rubix works just fine as well. (Incidentally, I re-enabled IE Enhanced Security Configuration after install and it still seems to be working ok.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when i tried to update to the latest version.

It worked after i uninstalled SourceTree, restarted the PC and reinstall it.